# How to locate an element with multiple attributes using Ext.componentQuery.query in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I want to know if can we use multiple attributes in componentquery in `extjs` to locate an element?

Like the below query searches the button with name as `mybutton`. Can we add more attributes like class and text in the same query ?

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[b-name="mybutton"]')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Let's say this is the element you are looking for:

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    id:'iAmId',
    itemsId: 'iAmItemId',
    text: 'Hnweis: Bitte Projekt im SAP/SRM abrechnen.',
    style: {
        'font-weight': 'bold'
    }
}
```

This is the component query you can run if you want to look for this element on basis of its id and itemId:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('label[itemsId="iAmItemId"][id="iAmId"]')
```